# SQL Server: convert ((int)year,(int)month,(int)day) to Datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a date with T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266924/create-a-date-with-t-sql)

I've a data table that stores each year, month and day value as ints:

```
year | month | day
2009 |   1   |  1 
2008 |  12   |  2
2007 |   5   |  5
```

I need to convert it to datetime value, because I need to use it in a datetime between operation. How could I do this?

Comment: This has been asked a few times.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266924/create-a-date-with-t-sql

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In order to be independent of the language and locale settings, you should use the ISO 8601 `YYYYMMDD` format - this will work on any SQL Server system with any language and regional setting in effect:

```
SELECT
   CAST(
      CAST(year AS VARCHAR(4)) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(month AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(day AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
   AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: thanks, I did it that way too.

Comment: YYYYMMDD works like magic!

Comment: Doesn't work with Firebird 2.5 though, only `YYYY-MM-DD` does

Comment: @Fr0sT: I **specifically** said this is for **SQL Server** ...

Comment: @marc_s calling "MS SQL Server" a "SQL server" is always confusing me. It's like saying "smartphone" meaning "iPhone" only or "OS" meaning "Windows" only.

Comment: @Fr0sT: **SQL Server** however ***IS*** the official product name! If you want to refer to the class of products, use "database server" or "RDBMS" or something like that. ....

Comment: @marc_s yep, Redmond guys sometimes "rock" in naming...

Comment: For different locales SQL Server has `DATEFORMAT` setting. See usage here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27355251/1665649

Comment: You can also use select DATEFROMPARTS(year, month, day) as MyDateValue

Comment: @MarceloLujan: yes - with SQL Server **2012** or newer, you can - but earlier versions didn't have that function

Answer (score 38):

Pure datetime solution, does not depend on language or DATEFORMAT, no strings

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(year, [year]-1900, DATEADD(month, [month]-1, DATEADD(day, [day]-1, 0)))
FROM
    dbo.Table
```

Comment: This does require SQL to be configured with 1900 as base date though

Comment: @AdriaanDavel SQL Server (the question tags) is *always* base date 01 Jan 1900. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql see "default value".

Answer (score 8):

You could convert your values into a 'Decimal' datetime and convert it then to a real datetime column:

```
select cast(rtrim(year *10000+ month *100+ day) as datetime) as Date from DateTable
```

See [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/get-date-only.aspx) as well for more info.

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(year AS varchar) + '/' + CAST(month AS varchar) + '/' + CAST(day as varchar) AS datetime) AS MyDateTime
FROM table
```

Comment: that's a bad idea - this is dependent on the local settings for your date format.

Comment: @marc_s understood, but depending on your deployment needs, it may be a mute point.

Comment: naw.  If it is a one time ad-hoc query, I could see your point. But not in a stored procedure.  marc_s has a good point!