# Converting three int parameter to one date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, function

Consider three parameters:

```
@Y=2014
@M=11
@D=24
```

I want to have a function in SQL Server which gets three numbers and return one date as result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use SQL Server 2012 [DATEFROMPARTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) function.

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, @day)
```

For versions below 2012, I'd use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, STR(@year * 10000 + @month * 100 + @day))
```

Comment: sqlserver 2008 please

Comment: @Behnam, tag the question appropriately

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
select cast(cast( (@y * 10000 + @m * 100 + @d) as varchar(255)) as date)
```

But `datefromparts()` is best if you are using SQL Server 2012+.

Comment: Its not working. `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`.

Comment: @NoDisplayName . . . I was overly enthusiastic with the `0` key.  Here is a SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/41140.

Comment: Good analytic skills

Answer (score 0):

```
create function dbo.formatDate(@Y int, @M int, @D int)
returns date
as
begin
    declare @retDate date
    select @retDate =  cast(cast(@Y as varchar) + '-' + cast(@M as varchar) + '-' + cast(@D as varchar) as date)
    return @retDate
end
```

Testing:

```
select dbo.formatDate(2014, 11, 24)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(day, '/', month, '/', year) AS Date
```

Comment: Good because it doesn't work in the United States and, bad because it doesn't work in the United States. etc.

Comment: it can be moved around to suit the country's date format

Comment: Oh, and the result is a `varchar` that looks like a date, not a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

this is a duplicate of this question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1923918/3632420

```
SELECT
   CAST(
      CAST(year AS VARCHAR(4)) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(month AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(day AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
   AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SQL Server 2000` and above use the below query

```
Select MyDate=cast(DateAdd(day, @DayOfMonth - 1, 
          DateAdd(month, @Month - 1, 
              DateAdd(Year, @Year-1900, 0))) as date)
```

If you are using `SQL Server 2012` and above use the built function [DATEFROMPARTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213228.aspx)
like

```
select DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, @day)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
declare  @Y int=2014
declare  @M  int =11 
declare  @D int =2

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), (SELECT Cast(@d AS VARCHAR(20)) + '-'
                                    + Cast(@M AS VARCHAR(20)) + '-'
                                    + Cast(@y AS VARCHAR(20))), 110)
```

Change the `110` accordingly needed for different formats

[formats in sql server datetime conversion](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)