# How to join numbers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have some data like this in a table:

```
year           month        day           ID
2013            1             1            x1
2013            1             2            x2
2013            1             3            x3
2013            1             4            x4
2013            1             5            x5
2013            1             6            x6
...
2016            4             10           x1500
```

This table is a customer table with customerID and customer apply date, but the apply date is split to year & mont & day , data from 2013/1/1 to 2016/4/10 , I want to get the customerID that apply after 2014/4/5.

Here's the code I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE [Year]+'-'+[Month]+'-'+[Day] > '2014-4-5'
```

But I got this error back:

> [Err] 22018 - [SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2014-4-5' to data type int.

Who can help me?

Comment: Check this, it will be the solution to your issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266924/create-a-date-with-t-sql

Comment: @David it is not really a good idea to produce a date from the columns. It will is not sargable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backs' solution is nice and easy (edit: but incorrect, thanks @t-clausen.dk for pointing that out), a different option would be [DATEFROMPARTS()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx):

```
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], [Day]) > '2014-04-05'
```

Edit: DATEFROMPARTS() is only available in sql-server 2012 and up.

Comment: @Backs solution is incorrect, it doesnt allow jan 2015 or 2015-01-01

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I just tested the sql , it runs ok ,why you say solution is incorrect? Thanks!

Comment: @Walker.li the query he wrote will not return any following years when month is from jan to april 5. It will not return 1-4 december, november etc 2014 either

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Thank you ! Though I can't test the error out , but I will remember it .

Answer (score 3):

This should work and keep your code [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE 
  [Year] = 2014 and [Month] = 4 and [Day] > 5
  OR [Year] > 2014
  OR [Year] = 2014 and [Month] > 4
```

Another useful method would be making a PERSISTED computed column, persisted columns are sargable and you can even put an index on that column:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD actualdate AS 
  CONVERT(date, cast(year as varchar(4))+'-' +
  cast(month as varchar(2)) +'-'+ cast(day as varchar(2)), 126) PERSISTED
```

Then you can simply type

```
WHERE actualdate > '2014-04-05'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is dependant on language settuings.See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923876/sql-server-convert-intyear-intmonth-intday-to-datetime) for more info..

```
create table #test
    (
    year int,
    month int,
    date int,
    name char(20)
    )


    insert into #test
    select 2012,1,14,'ab'


    ;with cte
    as
    (
    select *, datefromparts(year,month,date) as datee
     from #test
     )
     select * from cte where date>'somedate'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the columns `Year`, `Month` and `Day` to `varchar`.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM Customer
WHERE CAST((
  CAST([Year] as varchar(4)) + '-' + 
  CAST([Month] as varchar(2)) + '-' + 
  CAST([Day] as varchar(2)))
) > '2014-04-05';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE WHERE
DATEADD(year, [year]-1900, DATEADD(Month, [Month]-1, DATEADD(Day, [Day]-1, 0))) >  CAST('2014-4-5' AS DATETIME)
```

(OR)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE CAST(CAST([Year]+'-'+[Month]+'-'+[Day] AS VARCHAR(15)) AS DATETIME >  CAST('2014-4-5' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: [Year]+'-'+[Month]+'-'+[Day] this will return a numeric value and an incorrect result, once you convert it will translate into a date like: 1905-07-18,

Comment: second answer is still incorrect, you need to cast the individual columns