# use three parameters to create a date

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, date

how can i pass 3 parameters to form a date in sql 
for example
@year
@month
@day

Basically my program sends the parts of the date seperatly and i want them to be joined in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266924/create-a-date-with-t-sql) answer to a similar question.

> CAST(CAST(y AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(m
>   AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(d AS varchar)
>   AS DATETIME)

(I assume you know how to pass 3 parameters to stored procedure)

Comment: hmmm it works but i cant get a dateadd to work in there is it possible to subtract the generated year by a parameter

Answer (score 1):

Good link on SQL Date functions:

[SQLTeam Dates](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/01/02/56079.aspx)