# get the date and time for today at midnight and add to it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a sql command to get today's date at midnight and be able to add a number of minutes to it?

Comment: you mean how much minutes left until midnight?

Comment: no, i have to start_time and a finish_time... the start time needs to be midnight and the finish_time would be like n minutes later

Comment: if you know the time then shortest method may be: 
select cast(convert(varchar,getdate(),23) + ' 23:59:59' as datetime) 
and you can get start and end date as below:
select cast(convert(varchar,getdate(),23) + ' 23:59:59' as datetime) startTime, dateadd(minute,10,cast(convert(varchar,getdate(),23) + ' 23:59:59' as datetime)) endTime

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes,    just use datediff and dateadd functions to strip the time from any date, then add a fractional portion of a day to that number

```
Declare @aDate DateTime
Set @aDate = getDate()
Declare @Minutes Integer
Set @minutes = 600 -- 10 hours

Select DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, @aDate), 0) + @minutes / 1440.0  -- 1440 min/day
 -- or You could also use the dateadd again...
Select DateAdd(minute, @minutes , DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, @aDate), 0))
```

Both selects return 10:00 am on the same day (more or less).  This works because of, well, check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266924/create-a-date-with-t-sql/267016#267016)

EDIT: Added sample script to show how this works:

```
declare @dtTim datetime = getDate()
declare @today datetime = dateAdd(day, dateDiff(day, 0, @dtTim ), 0)
select  @dtTim, @today
```

Comment: Thank you.. and sorry I didn't search the site better

Comment: So does this mean that if I do:  

SET today = GETDATE();

SET start = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, today), 0);

it'll be set to midnight of the current day?

(couldn't use multiple '@' symbols in comments)
('midnight' of course meaning hour 00:00 of the day)

Comment: Yes, except your script needed some syntax corrections..... Added edit top my answer to demo

Answer (score 57):

Date now midnight time:

```
Select DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))
```

ADD 600 Minutes:

```
Select DATEADD(mi,600,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 15):

You can also cast to `date` to strip off the time portion:

```
declare @minutes int = 600
declare @start datetime = cast(getdate() as date)
declare @finish datetime = dateadd(mi, @minutes, @start)
```

Although, honestly, I have no idea how it performs compared to

`dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)`

Comment: for me, casting getdate to date did not work, i got an error complaining that "Type date is not a defined system type." - sql server 2005

Comment: @PeterPerháč `date` was added in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I compared `cast(getdate() as date)` and `dateadd(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, getdate()))` with a table of a few thousand rows.
**The cast was 10x faster** than the dateadd...

Answer (score 8):

Necromancing:

The simplest/fastest way is:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(minute, 1, 
        CAST(FLOOR(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS float)) AS datetime)   
    )
```

or with UTC:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(minute, 1, 
        CAST(FLOOR(CAST( GETUTCDATE() AS float)) AS datetime)   
    )
```

This works, because in SQL-server, datetime is a float value, the integer part representing the days from 01.01.1900, the sub-integer part represents the percentage of the full day (24h).

So if you round-down `(floor)` the floating-point number to a integer, you get the midnight-time. 
`1900-01-01T00:00:00.000` being 0.

Comment: Using the above, I get `2020-04-03 00:01:00.000`. I believe you want a 0 instead of a 1. `SELECT DATEADD(minute, 0, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS float)) AS datetime))`

Comment: @David Metcalfe: The question was how to add to it - this demonstrates that with +1 minute.

Answer (score 2):

Use following:

```
select DATEADD(SECOND, 36000, CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS datetime))
```

This way you can adjust the seconds to pinpoint any time of day you want.

Please refer to this for date/time formatting in SQL Server:
[SQL Server Date/Time Formatting](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I had to do something similar, create a procedure to run from a certain time the previous day to a certain time on the current day This is what I did to set the start date to 16:30 on the previous day, basically subtract the parts you don't want to get them back to 0 then add the value that you want it to be.

```
-- Set Start Date to previous day and set start time to 16:30.00.000

SET @StartDate = GetDate()
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(dd,- 1, @StartDate) 
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(hh,- (DatePart(hh,@StartDate))+16, @StartDate) 
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(mi,- (DatePart(mi,@StartDate))+30, @StartDate) 
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(ss,- (DatePart(ss,@StartDate)), @StartDate) 
SET @StartDate = DateAdd(ms,- (DatePart(ms,@StartDate)), @StartDate)
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then flag / vote to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.* Duplicate answer found [here](//stackoverflow.com/a/41609720/2747593).