# No Date Returned from Conversion

Tags: t-sql

There are values there for the 3 fields that make up the date here, but I get null back..so something is wrong with my syntax.  I also want just the date (no time) `

```
   case when isdate(CAST(someTable.DATE_MM as varchar(8)) + CAST(someTable.DATE_DD as varchar(8)) + CAST (someTable.DATE_YY as varchar(8))) = 1
        then convert(date,CAST(someTable.DATE_MM as varchar(8)) + '/' + CAST(someTable.DATE_DD as varchar(8)) + '/' + CAST (someTable.DATE_YY as varchar(8))) else null end as BirthDate,
```

that's in my select statement and it's giving me NULL for the data.  The values for those 3 fields are:

```
DATE_MM: 3
DATE_DD: 4
DATE_YY: 1959
```

the data type behind those 3 fields is int

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266924/create-a-date-with-t-sql

Comment: @Tejs, that works but do you know how to get just the Date from the cast (strip out time)?

Comment: ok resolved I came up with doing a convert instead of cast via that example you sent from that other post.

Answer (score 0):

You merge 3 varchar values together, it will return a varchar, therefore your isdate will return false and your case will return the null value from the else clause.

Comment: well then how do I combine them together.  I don't want to do int +  int+ int ...that's adding, not appending the parts together to make a date so that the convert will work.  So I'm doing it via varchar so I can append those together...

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with `dateadd` instead.

```
select dateadd(day, DATE_DD - 1, 
               dateadd(month, DATE_MM - 1, 
                       dateadd(year,  DATE_YY - 1900, 0))) as BirthDate
from someTable
```