# BETWEEN clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, between

I have a SQL statement to display data between two dates. I almost got it but there's a problem.

If I input `March 1,2012 to March 7, 2012`.. it should show data with dates between the two.. but it also show all of the dates under March 2012.. but whenever I input March 10, 2012 to March 30, 2012 the SQL works perfectly.. any help will be appreciated. thanks

```
SELECT 
   agentname, noofcalls, qualified, booking, resched, 
   actualbooking, sales, remarks, 
   concat(month,' ',day,',',year) as 'date' 
FROM 
   tblagents
WHERE 
   (month between '" & cbosmonth.Text & "' AND '" & cboemonth.Text & "')
   AND (day between '" & cbosday.Text & "' AND '" & cboeday.Text & "')
   AND (year between '" & cbosyear.Text & "' AND '" & cboeyear.Text & "')"
```

Comment: Why don't you store a date in a single field (with appropriate for date arythmetics type)?

Comment: This looks like an [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack waiting to happen.

Comment: @zerkms can you teach me how?

Comment: @user1841167: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

Comment: do you have a `datetime` type in your database?

Comment: It would be better to store to a date to the database instead of 3 separate integers. You could then converter you comboboxes' values into a Date object and compare this.

Comment: @zerkms does this work even though my dates are concatenated?

Comment: @user1841167: I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko but the thing is my date are concatenated... i've done it on datetimepicker but nothing happend

Comment: Can you edit the question with the database version, and the application language used?

Answer (score 3):

you are doing string comparisons in each of your 'between'. Every number starting with a 1, a 2 or a 3, regardless of what follows it, i.e. 21, or 26, or 31, they are all lower than 7 if you look at them as strings. 1 to 30 works because you're only leaving 31 behind, and 30 < 31 as a String as well.

Do the concatenation first and then the between:

```
WHERE concat(month,' ',day,',',year) 
      BETWEEN concat(cbosmonth.Text,' ', cbosday.Text,' ',cbosyear.Text)
      AND concat(cboemonth.Text,' ', cboeday.Text,' ',cboeyear.Text)
```

(check out for correct syntax, I'm just copy pasting from your question, not tried it)

BTW, unless you have a reason to, you probably should be storing the entire date in a single column with the right data time (datetime, timestamp, ...) and not three separated columns.

Comment: I've tried the codes but I got the 'Operand should contain one column(s)' error... i have no date column in my database.. the date only comes from the concatenation of the three columns... Thanks

Comment: you have a date alias in your SELECT.

Comment: ah, my bad, you can't refer to the alias in the WHERE clause because it's executed before the column value is determined. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is the incorrect way to store a date in database.
Change the date column to datatype **date**.

You could then do:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE bookingDate between to_date ('2012/03/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
AND to_date ('2012/03/07', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach is wrong.

In order for a date to be between two interval dates it does not have to have a day number between the two dates, e.g. (pseudocode)

- `date = May-25-2012;  startDate = March-15-2012, endDate = June-01-2012`
- `date` is clearly between `startDate` and `endDate`, yet
- `day(date)` is 25, which is not between `day(startDate) = 15` and `day(endDate) = 1`
- more, as 15 is larger than 1, there are no numbers between them, so that condition will always be false

Similar example can be made for the month part of the date (e.g. `date = May-25-2012;  startDate = September-15-2010, endDate = Match-01-2015`)

You need to take the values for day, month, year, and construct a Date either in the application or on the server and use that to compare the values against.

---

To make a date from text fields in VB

```
Dim startDate = new DateTime( 
      Convert.ToInt32(cbosyear.Text), 
      Convert.ToInt32(cbosmonth.Text), 
      Convert.ToInt32(cbosday.Text))
```

Note that this will fail if the user enters, e.g. "some text" for the year value. You'll need to add some data validations to achieve that.

To make a datetime from parts in SQL Server, [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266924/create-a-date-with-t-sql), there are quite a few techniques explained.

Also, you should *always* avoid just pasting values into the sql string, that's asking for sql injection problems. You should do something like this:

```
Dim command = new SqlCommand()
command.CommandText = "SELECT .... FROM tblagents where DATEFROMPARTS(year, month, day) between @startDate AND @endDate"
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", startDate)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", endDate)
```

Comment: Oh I just realized what you said.. I'll try to construct a Date.. BTW, app language is vb.net and sql server as my database