# Get a datetime from year, day of the year and hour in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in a Microsft SQL Server 2008 R2, which came from an outside source. The columns of the are as follows: `ID, Year, DAY, HOUR & Value`, where `DAY` contains the day of the year (from 1 to 366) and `HOUR` represents the hour of the day (from 0 to 23).

I wish to create a new datetime column and populate it with the dateTime created from the data in `Year, DAY & HOUR` columns.

What SQL function should I use to create the `DateTime` from its parts?

SQL Server 2012 has [`DATETIMEFROMPARTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213233.aspx), but there is no equivalent function for [SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/267016/327074

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
declare @Year int = 2003
declare @Day int = 100
declare @Hour int = 13

select dateadd(hour, @Hour, dateadd(dayofyear, @Day - 1, dateadd(year, @Year - 1900, 0)))
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I did not know that 0 represents 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the following instead:

```
DECLARE @day int, @month int, @year int
SELECT @day = 4, @month = 3, @year = 2011

SELECT dateadd(mm, (@year - 1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , @day - 1)
```

That will give you your date (though it is true that SQL 2012 gets it right, finally!)

To use it when you have year, day of the year and hour of the day, use the following:

```
declare @year int, @dayofyear int, @hourofday int
select @year = 2013, @dayofyear = 120, @hourofday = 12

select dateadd(hh, @hourofday, dateadd(yy, @year - 1900, dateadd(dd, @dayofyear - 1, 0)))
```

Comment: I don't have month, or day of the month. I have only Year, day of the year, and hour of the day.

Comment: I've updated to use your available fields, which could probably be shortened, but it works nonetheless!

Answer (score 3):

Created that for myself and thought it would be a good place to share - it is based on the sample by Mikael Eriksson.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DATETIME2FROMPARTS](
    @year int,
    @month int,
    @day int,
    @hour int,
    @minute int,
    @second int,
    @fractions int,
    @precision int)
RETURNS datetime2(7)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        DATEADD(NANOSECOND, POWER(10, 9-@precision)*@fractions, 
        DATEADD(SECOND, @second, 
        DATEADD(MINUTE, @minute, 
        DATEADD(HOUR, @hour, 
        DATEADD(DAY, @day-1, 
        DATEADD(MONTH, @month-1, 
        DATEADD(YEAR, @year-1900, 
        CAST(CAST(0 AS datetime) AS datetime2(7)))))))));
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution:

```
create table yourtable (yr int, dy int, hr int);
insert into yourtable values (2013,100,5);
insert into yourtable values (2013,1,1);

select dateadd(hour,hr,dateadd(month, (yr - 1900) * 12 , dy - 1))
from yourtable
```

The concept is add the hours to the date, using the year as (year - 1900) * 12 as the month, beginning with the number of days.