# How to sort multiple columns in SQL Server according to the date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server. Can you please tell me how can I sort this table according to the Year, Month, Day, Time? So that I can display other columns like "NAME" in the correct ascending order of the date.

I was using the following SQL query, but this returns result in ascii character order:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE YEAR = '2016' 
ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH, DDATE, TIME
```

Doesn't sort by date. Can you please show me with an example how to achieve this.

I have a SQL Server table that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You need to combine year, month, ddate, and time into a single value such as the julian date or minutes since epoch and sort on that. Here is a calculator `http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/JulianDate.php`

Comment: The Month part is messing you up; March should be 3, April should be 4, etc. As Marichyasana infers, you could create a computed column made up of a concatenation of those values, like 20160330, 20160304, etc.

Comment: `order by YEAR, MONTH(MONTH+' 1 2000'), DDATE, TIME` or create a DateTime2 from the parts and order by that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298624/get-a-datetime-from-year-day-of-the-year-and-hour-in-sql-server-2008-r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As B. Clay suggested month is probably not doing what your thinking, since it looks like that's a varchar or similar it's just going to order it alphabetically.

try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
where YEAR = '2016' order by 
YEAR, DATEPART(MM,MONTH + ' 1 2016'), DDATE, TIME
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e345e/9

Related: [Convert month name to month number in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314310/convert-month-name-to-month-number-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thank you for both Zoidz and zzbomb. After combing this code with `CONVERT(Int,DDATE), CONVERT(TIME, TIME)` it worked well. Thanks for both of you for showing me with an example

Answer (score 1):

First of all. You should use only one column for a date whenever is possible.

But in your case, your columns are VARCHAR type. Try something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where YEAR = '2016' 
order by 
   CONVERT(Int,YEAR), 
   (CASE MONTH
        WHEN 'January' THEN 1
        WHEN 'February' THEN 2
        WHEN 'March' THEN 3
        WHEN 'April' THEN 4
        WHEN 'May' THEN 5
        WHEN 'June' THEN 6
        WHEN 'July' THEN 7
        WHEN 'August' THEN 8
        WHEN 'September' THEN 9
        WHEN 'October' THEN 10
        WHEN 'November' THEN 11
        WHEN 'December' THEN 12), 
  CONVERT(Int,DDATE), 
  CONVERT(TIME, TIME)
```