# sql - date comparison using separate date part fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a statictics table which stores stats using separate fields for the parts of the date:

> dayNumber
>   monthNumber
>   yearNumber

this works great when i need for a specific date.

I am wondering how to work with this, when i need a date range, say between this date, to that date.

many thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266924/create-a-date-with-t-sql for different ways to combine day, month and year integers to create date. Check Charles Bretana's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   CAST(
    CAST(yearNumber as char(4)) 
    + '-'
    + CAST(monthNumber as char(2)) 
    + '-'
    + CAST(dayNumber as char(2)) 
  as smalldatetime) 
  BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Comment: Thanks Outis. I am using `SELECT TOP 40 tblCompanies.companyID, companyName, SUM(clicksLink) as mytotal  FROm tblCompanies INNER JOIN tblCompanyClicks ON tblCompanies.companyID  =tblCompanyClicks.companyID

 WHERE
 CAST(    CAST( yearNumber as char(4))     + '-'    + CAST(monthNumber as char(2))     + '-'    + CAST( dayNumber as char(2))   as datetime)  > GETDATE()-12
  
  GROUP BY tblCompanies.companyID, companyName
  order by mytotal desc`   but its coming up as empty, even though there are definitely stats there for the last 12 days

Comment: GETDATE() - 12 doesn't mean anything, because GETDATE() returns a datetime data type and 12 is an int data type. You need something like `< DATEADD(dd,-12,GETDATE())` if you want the date to be more than 12 days ago, and `< DATEADD(hh,-12,GETDATE())` if you want the date to be more than 12 hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

Reinforcing [zfus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2554537/zfus) comment to look at [Charles Bretana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/267016/366335), you can use `DATEADD` to build the date for comparison in the `WHERE` clause:

```
...
WHERE DATEADD(yy, yearnumber - 1900,  
              DATEADD(m, monthnumber - 1, daynumber - 1))
      BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;
```

[<kbd>SQL fiddle</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/04491/3)

Comment: Thanks beargle. same as above - i am using the following revised query, but it comes up as empty, even there is data for the last 12 days - `SELECT TOP 40 companyID, SUM(clicksLink) as mytotal  FROm  tblCompanyClicks 
 WHERE DATEADD(yy, yearnumber - 1900,  
              DATEADD(m, monthnumber - 1, daynumber - 1)) > GETDATE()-12
  GROUP BY companyID
  order by mytotal desc`

Comment: This is technically a different (but related) topic from your original question. The problem is likely related to date subtraction (look at [DATEADD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)), but my recommendation is to create a new question (with sample table structure _AND_ data). Please also keep in mind that it's difficult to read multi-line code in the comments section.