# select date in form dd/mm/yyyy in sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string-concatenation

in database table I got :

```
int day
int month
int year
```

I want to write a select query to show the date : dd/mm/yyyy

I try this but didn't work :

1-

```
select (day + '\' + month + '\' + year) as xdate from table1
```

but give me an error

2-

```
select (day + '-' + month + '-' + year) as xdate from table1
```

it return the sum of these field : 2036 instead of  21/1/2014

any solution ?

Comment: sql server,mysql,other?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue using [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: Why do you write `select (day + '\' + month + '\' + year) as xdate from table1` if you expect `select (day + '/' + month + '/' + year) as xdate from table1` ? ` \ ` is escape character.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266924/create-a-date-with-t-sql

Comment: datebase is : sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select (cast(day as varchar(2)) + '/' 
    + cast(month as varchar(2)) + '/' 
    + cast(year as varchar(4))) as xdate 
from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

If TSQL / SQL-SERVER, then `+` only works to concatenate *strings*...  So do some conversions on your numbers in that case:

```
select
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, day) + '\' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, month) + '\' ... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are Casting int to Varchar, so you need to use CAST or CONVERT function

## [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Try like this

```
select (Cast(day AS Varchar(10)) + '\' + Cast(month AS Varchar(10)) + '\' + Cast(year AS Varchar(10))) as xdate from table1
```

**(Or)**

```
select (Cast(day AS Varchar(10)) + '-' + Cast(month AS Varchar(10)) + '-' + Cast(year AS Varchar(10))) as xdate from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

[CONVERT(date, , 103)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) converts a date to a string representation in dd/mm/yyyy form

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,DATEFROMPARTS([year],[month],[day]),103)
```