# Convert month and year combination to date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have month and year in separate columns, i want to take records between two points (ie, a start date and end date). I have month and year alone. One solution i have  found is convert date,month combination into date .Say i have

```
Start month : 3 Start year : 2010
End month : 6 End year : 2013
```

I want to convert them as

```
 start date = 01-03-2010 

 End date = 31-06-2013
```

Any solutions?

Comment: start month is easy enough. end month will be hard since you need to figure out what the last day of the specified year/month is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266924/create-a-date-with-t-sql

Comment: Whoever designed this table should be fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Marc B** said, End month will be hard since you need to figure out what the last day of the specified year/month is.

Try this

```
DECLARE @StartMonth INT = 3 
DECLARE @StartYear INT = 2010 
DECLARE @EndYear INT = 2013 
DECLARE @EndMonth INT = 6 

SELECT Dateadd(year, @StartYear - 2000,Dateadd(month, @StartMonth - 1, '20000101')) AS StartDate, 
       Dateadd(year, @EndYear - 2000, Dateadd(month, @EndMonth - 1, '20000101')) AS EndDate
```

Answer (score 7):

SqlServer 2012 onward supports **DATEFROMPARTS**(). It can be done this way :

```
    DECLARE @Month as int, @Year as int
    SET @Month = 8
    SET @Year = 2018
    SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,@Month,'01')
```

To get last date of month you can use **EOMONTH**() as below :

```
    SELECT EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,@Month,'01'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Following is the way to find month last and first date by passing month and year

```
DECLARE @month varchar(2)
DECLARE @year varchar(4)
```

**First date of month**

```
set @month='03'
set @year='2010'
select cast(@year + '-' + @month + '-01' as date)
```

*output*

```
2010-03-01
```

**Last date of month** (Increment your month by 1 then subtract 1 day)

```
set @month='06'
set @year='2013'
select CAST(cast(@year + '-' + Cast(cast(@month as int )+1 as varchar(20)) + '-01' as datetime)-1 as DATE)
```

*output*

```
2013-06-30
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
select convert(date, cast(startyear*10000 + startmon*100 + 1 as varchar(8)), 112)
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dateparts are stored as ints you could do something simply like cast them to varchar, concatenate, and cast again. For example:

```
DECLARE @StartYear INT = 2012
DECLARE @StartMOnth INT = 6

SELECT CAST(CAST(@StartYear AS CHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(@StartMonth AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-01' AS DATE)
```

On the end date you can use a CASE statement to identify the last day of the month. And don't forget leap years.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql function

```
Select cast(('01-'+h.[monthyear]) as date) from table1 h
```