# select data only by month and year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with month and year:[maintable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKcT4.jpg)

[image]

What I want is a range selection:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdKDU.jpg)

[image]

I thought between would be my friend and I tried the following:

```
SELECT        jahr, monat, alles
FROM            dbo.table
WHERE        (jahr BETWEEN 2017 AND 2018) AND (monat BETWEEN 11 AND 2)
```

But this does not work.
How can I get what I want?

Comment: `BETWEEN` boundaries have to have the low number on the left and the higher number on the right. As written, your second `BETWEEN` clause will never evaulate to true. You could either use `NOT BETWEEN` or you could use an `IN` clause instead

Comment: I know it's not usually feasible to refactor the data structure, but there's a specific data type for this: `date`. It would be better suited to this task. It would simplify the query and (as a bonus), save a bit of space.

Comment: with this solution i get also the combination 2017 1 and 2017 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert month and year combination to date in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138553/convert-month-and-year-combination-to-date-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
SELECT  jahr, monat, alles 
FROM table1
WHERE cast(cast(jahr as varchar(20))+'-'+cast(monat as varchar(20))+'-01' as date) >=  '2017-11-01'
 and cast(cast(jahr as varchar(20))+'-'+cast(monat as varchar(20))+'-01' as date) <='2018-02-01'
```

I think this is the best solution because you having the server deal with the details -- you are taking your data model and converting to a date type and then having the server do a date compare for the filter.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/13a69/21/0

Debug

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/13a69/20/0

Comment: tried it also with plus sign instead of pipe, getting the error message that explicit converting from int to date is not allowed

Comment: Looks like pipe pipe (||) is oracle only

Comment: @keithl -- pipe pipe is sql standard for concat strings.

Comment: @frank I changed it above to cast your integers to strings before the concatenate.

Comment: @frank -- I used jay's sql fiddle to get the syntax exactly right

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that jahr and monat are integer formats you can make a key out of them and can do a comparison that way.  You essentially end up with YYYYMM format.

```
SELECT        jahr, monat, alles
FROM            dbo.table
WHERE (jahr*100) + monat between 201711 and 201802
```

Comment: this is nice solution, but i have a problem with the plus sign. what to do with the plus sign in dynamic sql?

Comment: @frank if the plus sign in inside your single quote it shouldn't be an issue.  Just make sure it's treated as a part of the text like you other reserved words (select, from, etc....)

Comment: i wrote it that way, everything inside the string:

Comment: i wrote it that way, everything inside the string: SET query = 'select * from table WHERE (jahr*100) + monat between ' + von + ' and ' + bis + '. error is: error converting nvarchar 'select * from table WHERE (jahr*100) + monat between ' in int datatype, please imagin the at-sign in front of variables

Comment: @frank ok I see your issue. You need to convert von and bis to varchar inorder to concatenate them like strings

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the two dates as simple as follows in different conditions.

Compare the date is above the 2017 November (mont <=12 is used as a safety check, you can ignore that if you can guarantee the month column doesn't contain values greater than 12).

```
jahr >= 2017 AND monat >= 11 AND mont <=12
```

else you can use between
    jahr >= 2017 AND monat between 11 AND 12

Compare the date is below the 2018 February (mont >= 1 is used as a safety check, you can ignore that if you can guarantee the month column doesn't contain values less than 1).

```
jahr <= 2018 AND monat >= 1 AND mont <=2
```

else you can use between

```
jahr >= 2017 AND monat between 1 AND 2
```

The Whole condition with simple operators

`(jahr >= 2017 AND monat >= 11 AND monat <=12) 
    AND (jahr <= 2018 AND monat >= 1 AND monat <=2)`

With between conditions

`(jahr >= 2017 AND monat between 11 AND 12)
    AND (jahr >= 2017 AND monat between 1 AND 2)`

Following is the exact sql for your problem. All three queries should work for your purpose.

```
-- With simple operators
SELECT        jahr, monat, alles
FROM          dbo.table
WHERE         (jahr >= 2017 AND monat >= 11 AND monat <=12) 
AND (jahr <= 2018 AND monat >= 1 AND monat <=2)

-- With simple operators (Without security boundary checks)
SELECT        jahr, monat, alles
FROM          dbo.table
WHERE         (jahr >= 2017 AND monat >= 11) 
AND (jahr <= 2018 AND monat <=2)

-- With between operator
SELECT        jahr, monat, alles
FROM          dbo.table
WHERE         (jahr >= 2017 AND monat between 11 AND 12)
AND (jahr >= 2017 AND monat between 1 AND 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT        jahr, monat, alles
FROM           dbo.table
WHERE (jahr = 2017 AND monat IN (11,12))
      OR (jahr = 2018 AND monat IN (1,2))
```

Output

```
jahr    monat   alles
2017    11      105
2017    12      105
2018    1       104
2018    2       105
```

Demo Link

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/13a69/1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        jahr, monat, alles
FROM            dbo.table
WHERE        ( jahr = 2017 AND monat BETWEEN 11 AND 12 )
             OR 
             ( jahr = 2018 AND monat BETWEEN 1 AND 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
SELECT        jahr, monat, alles
FROM           table1
WHERE CASE WHEN (jahr = 2017 AND monat BETWEEN 11 AND 12) THEN 1
            WHEN (jahr = 2018 AND monat BETWEEN 1 AND 2) THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 END = 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OR operator and some parenthesis:

```
DECLARE @maintable TABLE (jahr int, monat int, alles int)
INSERT INTO @maintable VALUES
(2017, 7, 189),(2017, 8, 125),(2017, 9, 92),(2017, 10, 98),(2017, 11, 105)
,(2017, 12, 105),(2018, 1, 104),(2018, 2, 105),(2018, 3, 99)

SELECT jahr
      ,monat      
      ,alles 
  FROM @maintable
WHERE (jahr >= 2017 AND monat >= 11)
      OR
      (jahr <= 2018 AND monat <= 2)
```

Produces:

```
jahr    monat   alles
2017    11      105
2017    12      105
2018    1       104
2018    2       105
```