# Setting specific dates for a variable in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2005

I would lake to specify a specific datetime variable to be used. The code would look something like this:

```
Declare @Year = int
Declare @JanDate = Datetime

Set @JanDate = ???
```

I would like to set @JanDate to Month=1, Day =25, Year = @Year. Not sure what to put in for that?

Comment: Set Year = 2014, @year + '-01-25' would be my best guess.

Comment: The year is a user defined variable. I need the JanDate to be a specific month and day but use the user input @Year.

Comment: you basically just parse out the year, and insert your variable + whatever specific month and day you want to use

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
Declare @Year int;
SET @Year = 2013;
Declare @JanDate  Datetime;

SET @JanDate = CAST(
                CAST(@Year AS NVARCHAR(4)) + CAST('01' AS NVARCHAR(2)) +  CAST('25' AS NVARCHAR(2))
                AS DATETIME)
SELECT @JanDate


RESULT: 2013-01-25 00:00:00.000
```

**Or simply**

```
Declare @Year int;
SET @Year = 2013;
Declare @JanDate  Datetime;

SET @JanDate = CAST(
                CAST(@Year AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '01' +  '25'
                AS DATETIME)
SELECT @JanDate 

RESULT: 2013-01-25 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: I get an error with that code "Type DATE is not a defined system type"

Comment: @M.Ali Also, there is no real need to convert to `DATE` when you could avoid any potential problem by converting directly to `DATETIME`

Comment: @user3532047 it is because you didnt mention your sql server edition in your question and datatype `DATE` was introduced in sql server 2008 version. Also the inline variable declaration value assignment is something you can only do in sql server 2008 and later editions.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using SQL Server 2012, use one of the [DATEFROMPARTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx), [DATETIMEFROMPARTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213233.aspx), [DATETIME2FROMPARTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213312.aspx), OR [SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213396.aspx) functions.  You are on SQL 2005, so these functions are not available, but I am including them anyway in case someone on 2012 or higher finds this question in the future.

For example:

```
declare @Year int = 2014
declare @JanDate datetime

select @JanDate = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(@Year, 1, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

For the poster and those of us still using SQL Server 2005, you can concatenate a string together and convert that to a date:

```
declare @Year int = 2014
declare @JanDate datetime

select @JanDate = CAST(CAST(@Year as varchar) + '-1-25' as varchar)
```

Or, see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266924/create-a-date-with-t-sql/10142966#10142966) for a possibly more efficient way using multiple DATEADD functions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like casting strings to dates. Neither should you.

If you using SQL Server 2012 or later then you can use the answersuggested by Paul Williams i.e. `DateFromParts` or similar functions.

For earlier versions here's the method I would use:

```
DECLARE @Year    int;
DECLARE @JanDate datetime;

SET @Year = 2014;

SET @JanDate = DateAdd(dd, 25 - 1, DateAdd(yy, @Year - 1900, '1900-01-01'));

SELECT @JanDate;
```

It might seem overly complicated to some, but the way in which it performs the action is much more pleasing [to me] as it uses nothing but dates and integers.

Starting at SQL Servers base date `1900-01-01` we add on the number of years supplied (correcting by 1900 years `;-)`)

Then we add on the number of days (again, a correction of 1 day is required as the date we're working with is already the 1st of the month so adding 25 = 26, not the 25 we want).

---

Here's some supplementary code that you might find useful. Supply it any year, month and day it it will work it out for you.

If a user supplies "invalid" values (e.g. `2014-02-31` - there is no 31st of February) then the function will not fail, unlike a text to date casting. Instead it will provide the result `2014-03-03` which is 31 days after 1st Feb.

This logic might not please some people but it has always worked for me.

Enough waffling, here's the code:

```
DECLARE @y int
      , @m int
      , @d int;

SET @y = 2014;
SET @m = 6;
SET @d = 22;

SELECT DateAdd(dd, @d - 1, DateAdd(mm, @m - 1, DateAdd(yy, @y - 1900, '1900-01-01')));
```

-End transmission-

Comment: You are also (implicitly) casting `'1900-01-01'` to date though :)

Comment: @ypercube yeah, I know, shhh `;-)`. In all seriousness, I know someone would pick up on that. Normally I use `0` but thought I would make it a bit clearer for here.

Comment: No, I prefer this. Using `0` can be confusing.

Answer (score -2):

Your DECLARE statements may be incorrect depending on your version of SQL. The following should work (you'll just need to change @Year for the year you want):

```
DECLARE @Year int 
DECLARE @JanDate Datetime 
SET @Year=2013
SET @JanDate='1/25/'+CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR)
```

Comment: What's `mm`? Is it the edible M&M's?

Comment: @DaveJemison at the very least you should use an ISO format for dates: `YYYY-MM-DD`