# sql where date is bigger than integer date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure and table consists of integer for date for year, month, day.

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        [Address],
    FROM [dbo].[Stats]
    WHERE DATEADD(year, [year]-1900, DATEADD(month, [month]-1, DATEADD(day, [day]-1, DATEADD(hour, [hour]-1, DATEADD(minute, [minute]-1, 0))))) >= @datetime
END
```

If I pass datetime into stored procedure how can I do where statement. How can I simplifiy procedure below?

Also I tried this

```
DATEADD(year, [year]-1900, DATEADD(month, [month]-1, DATEADD(day, [day]-1, DATEADD(hour, [hour]-1, DATEADD(minute, [minute]-1, 0))))) as [DateTime]
FROM [dbo].[Stats]
AND [DateTime] >= @datetime
```

And it says [DateTime] doesn't exist, how can I assign AS new field from calculation in stored procedure? It works normal in query.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using (which is pretty obviously SQL Server).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Date in SQL Server given the Day, Month and Year as Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576983/how-to-create-a-date-in-sql-server-given-the-day-month-and-year-as-integers)

Comment: You cannot use an alias like `[DateTime]` in a where clause, you need to repeat the entire calculation again in your `AND` statement. I dont believe that is works like that in `normal query`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`datetimefromparts()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
WHERE datetimefromparts([year], [month], [year], [hour], [minute], 0)  >= @datetime
```

I'm not sure what the arithmetic you are doing for your conversion is for.  Obviously, you can include such expressions as arguments to the function.

Comment: datefromparts accept only 3 arguments

Comment: So where (datefromparts([year], [month], [year])  >= @datetime and datefromparts([hour], [minute], 0)  >= @datetime) ?

Comment: If you just have until day (no time), then use `datefromparts()`, if you want full datetime then `datetimefromparts()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DQ.Address, DQ.[DateTime]
      (SELECT *,
          DATEADD(year, [year]-1900, DATEADD(month, [month]-1, DATEADD(day, [day]-1, DATEADD(hour, [hour]-1, DATEADD(minute, [minute]-1, 0))))) 
             AS [DateTime] 
      )
           FROM [dbo].[Stats]) AS DQ
WHERE  DQ.[DateTime] >= @datetime
```